Registering existing unpublished app in Entra
We have a small daemon process that sends email on behalf of our customers.  The customer sets up an email address (an Exchange account) for us, and the daemon sends the mail through their Exchange server from that account.  The current code uses the userid and password to sign in; we want to move to modern authentication.
I have a working version using MS Graph API and the client credentials flow.  The daemon runs on our server (with access to our co-located database), authenticates app-to-app with the customer's tenant, and successfully sends emails.  We've tested with ourselves as the customer, so we've been able to work out how to grant permissions and so forth, but not initial registration.
We registered by creating a new app -- that's clearly not right for our customers.  I don't think publishing to the Entra Gallery is right either -- we will have a very small number of users, and they will have to have pre-existing contracts with us for other services.  All the documentation I've looked at assumes you're in one of those two situations.  How can our customers register our daemon in their tenant, so that we can authenticate with them via client credentials?
(Ideally, we'd like to do this programmatically, so we can give them an executable to run.  But a script to walk them through doing it manually would also work.)
